# Google Docs: Auto-numbering / Updating Exhibits and Figures

Tags: google-docs

If I have 10 different .jpg photos (each an exhibit) I would like label each figure. For example:

Figure 1: Photo of Left handed smoke shifter

As each figure object is added to the document, the number is automatically incremented:

Figure 2: Photo of Right handed smoke shifter

If a new figure is inserted between Figures 1 and 2, then #2 is renumbered as #3.  A table of figures is automatically generated & updated as needed.

I think this functionality exists in Word (maybe it has a canonical name?): does said functionality exist in G-docs?

I have used this feature in MS-Word: maybe there is a workaround that can achieve the same result?

https://www.avantixlearning.ca/microsoft-word/how-to-update-all-figure-numbers-in-microsoft-word/

Comment: I would like to know how to do this as well.